# Are digital signal processors categorised in ASIPs?

Tags: embedded, dsp, hardware

Reading Wikipedia, it seems like DSPs use short instruction sets specialized for digital signal processing with hardware designed to specifically accelerate these instructions (e.g. multiplying, accumulation etc.)
Going by definition of ASIP on Wikipedia (Which I don't understand well), DSP seems to be an ASIP. is this true?
[DSP on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor)
[ASIP on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_instruction_set_processor)

Comment: The answer would appear to be "maybe", but as a working EE I find such questions have no relevance to my job. I doubt DSP engineers lose much sleep over it either.

Answer (score 1):

ASIPS are instruction pipelines specifically tailored to a purpose, more along the lines of an FPGA where the algorithm is implemented on a hardware level. The algorithms can still be changed somewhat by loading different instructions. DSP's are not necessarily ASIPS because most DSPs do not have configurable logic.

An example of this would be intels new xeon chips that integrate re-configurable logic that can be tailored to specific algorithms.

Personally I think the term ASIP is perfectly useless.